# What is the apps for the the two icons shown

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, notification-bar

What apps are icons shown on the 3rd icon from the left (a icon that look like a bug with an android head) and the 5th icon from the left (a icon with a phone in between two zig-zag)?

[image: Notification bar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one you asked about means the phone is connected in debug mode to a computer:
[image]

and the phone between zig-zag lines means it's on vibration mode.

Comment: Please note that the USB debugging icon varies depending on the version of Android, for example in 4.0 (ICS) it is an ice cream sandwich shaped android, in 4.1 (JB) it is a jelly bean shaped android head, etc. Vibration mode icon has changed in new versions of Android too (currently being a tilted smartphone with straight lines surrounding it).